# plotting multiple values of x for one value of y in python

Tags: python, list, plot

I have a problem when trying to plot using plt.plot. My particular problem is that I have two lists. For every element of the first list I want to plot the corresponding 4 elements of the second list. This is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

lista=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
listb=[1,2,0,4,1,5,0,2,1,2,1,4,1,2,0,4]

i=0
j=0
l=0

while i<=5:
  while j<=3:
    X=listb[j+l*4]
    Y=lista[i]
    pl.plot(Y,X,'ro')
    j=j+1
  i=i+1
  l=l+1


pl.xlim(0,7)
pl.ylim(-1,5)
pl.show()
```

What I want is to create a graph that will have for every Y(element of lista) four values(elements of listb). But what I get is a graph with only the first element of lista

Comment: Please reformat the question, it's hard to read like this.

Comment: really sorry for that.

Comment: Your error is not to set j back to zero for each new i. A for-loop would do that better or list tricks.

Comment: you are absolutely wright/thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you do a little of the work upfront it will vastly simplify the code:

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
listb = [1,2,0,4,1,5,0,2,1,2,1,4,1,2,0,4]

listaexpanded = []
for e in lista:
    listaexpanded.extend([e] * 4)

for y,x in zip(listaexpanded, listb):
    pl.plot(y, x, 'ro')
```

As a general rule in python you mostly don't use while loops, and whenever you find yourself incrementing things as using them as indexes you want to rethink the code to avoid it. It's hard to read and very prone to "off by 1" errors.

Comment: Probably my question is badly posed because your answer is irrelevant to what I want to know.

Comment: Really? I don't have pylab installed but this should plot 16 different points (though due to duplication in your data only 15 are unique).